# Changing the color of terminal text output (macos)

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there a way to change the color of the text output from my program to the terminal.

For example - escape codes?

I'd like to hi-light the error messages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add color to your terminal output this way:

```
echo -e "This is a normal text color \033[1;31m This is a red text\033[0m. Back to normal."
```

`31` is for red, but you can try other values from 30 to 37.